# dict value can't be assigned while appending..?

Tags: python

If `valst` is a True list (containing elements), why does this work:

```
valst.append(seq)
id_seq_dict[id] = valst
```

But this does not work:

```
id_seq_dict[id] = valst.append(seq)
```

Is it because the append method returns nothing?

Comment: The append method returns `None`.

Comment: Yes.  that is correct

Comment: Exactly. `append()` returns `None` as well as `extend()` which I think is what you should have used here because you are appending a list to another list. Maybe you might want to `id_seq_dict[id] = valst + seq` but this won't mutate `valst`

Answer (score 0):

The `append()` method modifies the list and returns nothing (`None`) indeed.